# Ionic 4 - Conditions for Page getting added to the "Navigation Stack"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, url-routing

From the [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button) for the `<ion-back-button>` element:

"The back button navigates back in the app's history upon click. It is smart enough to know what to render based on the mode and when to show based on the **navigation stack**."

It seems like a misnomer, as I am working on a project (Ionic 4, Angular 10) that makes no reference to NavController, and "navigation stack" implies its based on some navigator object, when I believe it is actually based on the router.

I say this because a back button on this project works, but only on most pages. For some it does not appear unless a default hRef is specified, indicating that whatever stack is storing previous pages sometimes does not have pages added.

My problem is, I cannot discern what causes a page to be added or not be added to this stack. My project uses Router.navigate for moving between views, and some store the previous page for the back button and others do not.

So, my questions are thus: What are the conditions for ensuring a page gets added to the stack that `<ion-back-button>` is using? And are there any misconceptions I have with how this "navigation stack" works? Is this stack viewable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like u are looking for it:

Methods​

**canGoBack**​ Description  Returns true if the current view can go back.
Signature   canGoBack(view?: ViewController ｜ undefined) => Promise

**getActive**​ Description  Get the active view.
Signature   getActive() => Promise<ViewController ｜ undefined>

**getByIndex**​ Description Get the view at the specified index.
Signature   getByIndex(index: number) => Promise<ViewController ｜ undefined>

**getPrevious**​ Description    Get the previous view.
Signature   getPrevious(view?: ViewController ｜ undefined) => Promise<ViewController ｜ undefined>

**insert**​ Description Inserts a component into the navigation stack at the specified index.
This is useful to add a component at any point in the navigation stack.
Signature   insert(insertIndex: number, component: T, componentProps?: ComponentProps ｜ null ｜ undefined, opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**insertPages**​ Description    Inserts an array of components into the navigation stack at the specified index.
The last component in the array will become instantiated as a view, and animate
in to become the active view.
Signature   insertPages(insertIndex: number, insertComponents: NavComponent[] ｜ NavComponentWithProps[], opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**pop**​ Description    Pop a component off of the navigation stack. Navigates back from the current
component.
Signature   pop(opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**popTo**​ Description  Pop to a specific index in the navigation stack.
Signature   popTo(indexOrViewCtrl: number ｜ ViewController, opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**popToRoot**​ Description  Navigate back to the root of the stack, no matter how far back that is.
Signature   popToRoot(opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**push**​ Description   Push a new component onto the current navigation stack. Pass any additional
information along as an object. This additional information is accessible
through NavParams.
Signature   push(component: T, componentProps?: ComponentProps ｜ null ｜ undefined, opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise
removeIndex​
Description Removes a component from the navigation stack at the specified index.
Signature   removeIndex(startIndex: number, removeCount?: number, opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**setPages**​ Description   Set the views of the current navigation stack and navigate to the last view.
By default animations are disabled, but they can be enabled by passing options
to the navigation controller. Navigation parameters can also be passed to the
individual pages in the array.
Signature   setPages(views: NavComponent[] ｜ NavComponentWithProps[], opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

**setRoot**​ Description    Set the root for the current navigation stack to a component.
Signature   setRoot(component: T, componentProps?: ComponentProps ｜ null ｜ undefined, opts?: NavOptions ｜ null ｜ undefined, done?: TransitionDoneFn ｜ undefined) => Promise

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav

Comment: Response appreciated, however, the project I am working on does not using ```<ion-nav>``` and I would like to continue with the existing Angular ```Router``` that much of the logic is currently based on. I'm unsure if these would be able to tell me whether something is on the "navigation stack" a ```Router``` would use either.

Comment: I think if u wanna bind the stack with the ion-back-button you have to use navController.
That works great on my projects!

Comment: But I have an ```<ion-back-button>``` in my project which does not use navController. It does work, not perfectly, but more often than not. This is why I believe you do not have to use navController.

Comment: And it doesn't appear if you don't put baseHref, right?

Comment: For some pages, baseHred is unneeded, and it works as expected, navigating to the previous page, even when the previous page is not the "home" page. For others, it does not appear unless baseHref is specified.

Comment: How would `canGoBack` be done in ionic 6?